# Windows crashes during games and video encoding

Tags: video, graphics-card, bsod, crash, gaming

Exactly as it says: I have an over two-year old gaming rig that sometime late last year decided to start crashing itself for no apparent reason when intensive tasks like video encoding and even gaming at high settings are active. I ran the Time Spy stress in extreme mode and scored like 91.7% frame stability, roughly five percentage points from a passing grade. Even in standard mode, it was slightly worse at 90.5%. Crash behavior is like 50/50 as well: either I get a black screen followed by a reboot, or I get blue screened with WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR... and the last time I blue screened from this was in my third round of *Overwatch* during the same game session (that is, without exiting the game or switching to another playlist). The graphics adapter is a GeForce 1070 with an AMD Ryzen 7 CPU.

Comment: Just be aware, there are few reasons for blue screens.. Driver error, actual hardware error.. or possible corruption of the file system (which is still driver error).  THATS IT.  If you have updated everything and still see and error.. you can try a complete reinstall of windows, or swap out the graphics card (assuming that the error is from the card) to see if it still happens.  Also.. have you looked at your COOLING? .. FANS?  are they still good?  Just some things I would do.

Comment: Thanks. I just got the dust out (was due for some cleaning) and ran my video encode test, got a near-immediate bsod (hypervisor_error this time) so I turned off the virtualizing in the BIOS (since I'm not using it for anything else) and will run it again.

Comment: And it's no good. It crashed on me again.

(Actually that's half true: mp4 ran fine but webm crashed the system.)

Comment: So specifically.. webm didn't do what you say.  User mode programs can't crash a protected mode operating system. I am still guessing that you have a problem with the graphics hardware.. but it *could be* any of your hardware (even a sata cable).. more info from the blue screen might help someone help you further.

Comment: I do have a 0x00000124 bug check that restarted the system.

Comment: And that's the WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR that I mentioned earlier, the one which occurred during that game session which ALSO occurred during the webm encode. I should note that I have already updated Windows to the latest bits, however as a precaution I will also check my game drivers.

Comment: Okay, so I tried updating the game drivers and the installation failed completely. I'm trying to find where the installation log is (if there's even one at all) because the message is rather generic and doesn't say anything about what happened.

Comment: No log file that I noticed, but I *did* manage to update the drivers manually. I'll see how things work out from here.

Comment: And I still have a problem. Crashed yet again, no error on screen and I just updated the [blank] drivers. And cleaned out the computer. And who knows what else. I give up for now.

Comment: Quick update. I just got out of *Overwatch* and for once I didn't crash mid-game. Aside from the encoding issue which I still have I think that the worst may be over with this. Thanks again!